# count occurrence of 2 properties in list of object c#

Tags: c#, list, object

I have 2 list of objects

```
   List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 


      new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "Android"},
      new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "Android"}
      new Student(){ StudentName="Steve",MobileOS = "IOS"},
      new Student(){ StudentName="Ram",  MobileOS = "IOS"},
      new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "IOS"}
}
```

In my other list, I want to store filtered data. Example

```
    List<FilteredData> filteredData= new List<FilteredData>(){

          new FilteredData(){ StudentName="Bill", Count=3, Android = 2, Ios = 1},
          new FilteredData(){ StudentName="Steve",Count=1, Android = 0, Ios = 1},
          new FilteredData(){ StudentName="Ram",  Count=1, Android = 0, Ios = 1},
}
```

**Noted:** the **Count** value is based on the occurrence of same **StudentName**
 and the number of **Android** and **Ios** is based on **MobileOS**

So, how can I count the same Student name and store it into a new list?
I searched whole day but seems can't found a solution for this

Comment: @mm8 basically filters the first list and store it into second list

Comment: @mm8 or do u have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
                new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "Android"},
                new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "Android"},
                new Student(){ StudentName="Steve",MobileOS = "IOS"},
                new Student(){ StudentName="Ram",  MobileOS = "IOS"},
                new Student(){ StudentName="Bill", MobileOS = "IOS"}
            };

            List<FilteredData> filteredData = studentList
                .GroupBy(x => x.StudentName)
                .Select(x => new FilteredData() {
                    StudentName = x.Key,
                    Count = x.Count(),
                    Android = x.Where(y => y.MobileOS == "Android").Count(),
                    Ios = x.Where(y => y.MobileOS == "IOS").Count()
                }).ToList();
        }
    }
        public class Student
        {
            public string StudentName { get;set;}
            public string MobileOS { get;set;}

        }
        public class FilteredData
        {
            public string StudentName { get;set;}
            public int Count { get;set;}
            public int Android { get;set;}
            public int Ios { get;set;}
        }


}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between this answer and mine except that you first call `Where` and then `Count()` which results in an un unnecessary extra iteration. You should use the overload of `Count` that accepts a predicate.

Comment: The comments says your code has errors.  Mine is complete including the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could group the results using LINQ:

```
List<FilteredData> filteredData = studentList
    .GroupBy(x => x.StudentName)
    .Select(x => new FilteredData()
    {
        StudentName = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count(),
        Android = x.Count(y => y.MobileOS == "Android"),
        Ios = x.Count(y => y.MobileOS == "Ios")
    }).ToList();
```

Note that this solution iterates each group three times but this shouldn't be an issue unless the number of items in `studentList` is huge. Then it might be a good idea to iterate through each group `x` manually and keep track of the numbers in three separate variables inside the `Select` func.

Comment: thanks, but your code have some error, should replace the x in `x.Mobile` with another variable

Comment: @StackOverFlowSavedMyLife: Changed to `y`.